# Unknown column When using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show the search result 'devname' form table devices
that is available in reports table so

```
public  function show_report()
    {
         $device = device::all();
         $reports = report::all();
         if (request()->has('keyword')) {
            $keyword = request()->keyword;
            $reports = report::latest() 
                ->where('title', 'like', "%$keyword%")
                ->orwhere($reports->device->devname, 'like', "%$keyword%")
                ->paginate(10);
        } else {
            $reports = report::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
        }
        return view('admin/reports.show_report', compact('dev', 'reports'));
    }
```

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$reports' in 'where clause'

Comment: A more descriptive title may help, there are a lot of people using laravel.

Comment: Does `$reports->device->devname` == `$reports`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
public function show_report(Request $request)
{
    $devices = Device::all();
    $reports = Report::query();

    if ($keyword = $request->keyword) { // here you can set variable $keyword
        $reports = $reports
            ->join('devices', 'reports.device_id', '=', 'devices.id') // use join to take devices table
            ->where('reports.title', 'like', "%$keyword%")
            ->orwhere('devices.devname', 'like', "%$keyword%");
    } 

    $reports = $reports->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);

    // in compact function the correct variable name is "devices", "dev" is an unknown variable
    return view('admin/reports.show_report', compact('devices', 'reports')); 
}
```